# Apply Math.log() in html page

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to use Math operation in Html page, but It is not working.
Below is the code that I have tried.
Is there any way to make this code to work.

html code

```
<div>  
<ul ng-style="{'height': Math.log10(data.value)*90 + 'px'}" 
ng-repeat="data in datas">
<li style="word-wrap: break-word;padding:0px 3px;"> {{name}}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Controller code

```
$scope.datas=[{"value":"1000000","name":"Name1"},{"value":"10","name":"Name2"}];
```

Here I am using angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math` is not defined in your scope definition, so the `ng-style` can't get a valid value from your code.

Instead, you should use a wrapper function like this:

**controller**

```
$scope.getPixels = function(value){
    return Math.log10(parseInt(value))*90
}
```

and in your **view**

```
ng-style="{'height': getPixels(data.value) + 'px'}"
```